# How to call JavaScript function in HTML without clicking any button?

Tags: javascript, html

My function is a timer that should run when the page is displayed. I wrote

```
<script>
    startcountdown();
</script>
```

In html but this doesn't work. How can I call that function? I don't need special event to happen before calling it.

Comment: Where the function is defined?

Comment: If `startcountdown` is manipulating `DOM`, you must wait for the DOM to be `ready`!

Comment: write your code at the end.

Comment: Its defined in a script file,... <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

Comment: <script>
    startcountdown();
</script> code

Comment: @SargsyanGrigor Can you provide the full source?

Comment: or even onload of body tag. eg. <body onload="startcountdown()" >

Comment: then your script.js file is not loaded.

Comment: Check console for errors ? Also define __doesn't work__

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript that executes after page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   startcountdown();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use JavaScripts native `window.onload` function, if you are not using any other library like jQuery or something else.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    startcountdown();
  };
</script>
```

I'd also like to mention that you could also start a function by just adding it to the end of your markup. That being said, if you define a function `function startcountdown() { }` at the very beginning of your html, you could simply use `startcountdown();` at the very end of your html (e.g. before your closing `</body>` tag).

This approach would simply execute your function **after** your DOM has being loaded, since it's defined as the last call of your markup.

Answer (score 2):

you can put it into tag using 'onload' event:

or just use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    yourFunct();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this put `onload="startcountdown();"` in html body tag

Answer (score 0):

By calling your function in page on-load

```
<script>
window.onload = startcountdown;
 function startcountdown(){
   //write your code here
}
</script>
```